# How do I change the queue behaviour in Banshee?

Tags: music, banshee

I've got a weird problem when I listen to one album and I shuffle through the other one (not activating its songs, just looking at track list etc.) and the track I listen to ends, banshee goes not to next track of the album I was listening to, but to 1st album of a track I am looking at. Maybe my description is a little bit confusing, so I'll upload a picture.

[image]

I'm listening to "Fire", but next song after that will be "Hush Now" instead of "Third Stone from the Sun" (next track on "Are You Experienced?").
Any ideas how to change it? I assume it's not a bug, just feature, but for me it's really annoying, because I like listening to whole albums, not single tracks.